Suddenly unable to automatically build docker image from dockerhub stored in bitbucket repo
I have a Dockerfile in a bit bucket repository, and have dockerhub configured to automatically build an image whenever I modify the Dockerfile. This was working fine (last worked 2024-08-29)  but today after making a minor edit to the file it is failing as follows
2024-10-10T14:56:03Z Cloning into '.'...
2024-10-10T14:56:03Z Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '104.192.142.24' to the list of known hosts.
2024-10-10T14:56:04Z git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
2024-10-10T14:56:04Z fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
2024-10-10T14:56:04Z 
2024-10-10T14:56:04Z Please make sure you have the correct access rights
2024-10-10T14:56:04Z and the repository exists.
2024-10-10T14:56:04Z please ensure the correct public key is added to the list of trusted keys for this repository (128)

Seems to be some of security issue but I haven't changed anything, what has changed, what is it trying to tell me?
Changing back the file to its previous version did not resolve the issue.

"after modifying the file it is failing as follows" -- kind-of obvious, have you tried reverting the changes?

Yes, the modification was minor and did not cause the issue, i should have made that clearer. have now posted answer and updated question.

So it turns out there was a security breach on dockerhub on 24/09/2024 that caused them to disconnect dockerhub builds from bitbucket repositories.  So the build not starting issue was resolved by relinking. Not very impressed I received no email or indication on the dockerhub site of what had happened.
